# Join two tables in a particular user session Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dreamweaver

I want to make a query using sql to merge two tables in a database where a particular value matches the current session id.

I'm using dreamweaver and i've added a recordset with this code but it doesn't display anything.

```
SELECT reg.username, reg.phoneno, gh.pay1
FROM reg INNER JOIN gh ON reg.username = gh.pay1
WHERE gh.username = colname
ORDER BY reg.id DESC
```

Here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/ed0mpx

When I take out the first two lines

```
SELECT reg.username, reg.phoneno, gh.pay1
FROM reg INNER JOIN gh ON reg.username = gh.pay1
```

It only display record for the first row. Other record doesn't show

Comment: Taking out the `WHERE` clause should make it show ALL rows.

Comment: BTW, those are the *last* two lines, not the *first* two lines.

Comment: Hi, i took out the WHERE and left it like this 
`SELECT reg.username, reg.phoneno, gh.pay1
FROM reg INNER JOIN gh ON reg.username = gh.pay1
 gh.username = colname
ORDER BY reg.id DESC`
but it's still not working

I added "AND" too

`SELECT reg.username, reg.phoneno, gh.pay1
FROM reg INNER JOIN gh ON reg.username = gh.pay1
AND gh.username = colname
ORDER BY reg.id DESC`
still didn't work.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?